# How to fix brightness keys not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, brightness, amd-graphics

I recently ran into a problem regarding my brightness control on my Lenovo Ideapad S145. The brightness keys are not working, and the slider in the top right corner is not working either.

A couple things worth mentioning:

I already tried the fixes where you edit the grub file. None of them worked.
The brightness control works on the login screen, but doesn't work when I actually log in.

My computer has AMD® A6-9225 radeon r4, 5 compute cores 2c+3g × 2 for the CPU, and AMD® Stoney for the Graphics, so I couldn't do the fixes where I add a conf file as most of the fixes I came across only showed me how to do it for Nvidia and Intel. I have AMD.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

I am very certain that this is a software issue.

Comment: The only simple thing I can think of that might help is that the brightness on a laptop is usually one of the function keys (for my Asus it's f5 & f6 to adjust brightness). Sometimes (and it's something you can adjust), you just hit that key, and sometimes you need to hold Fn whilst pressing the key - it depends on how the laptop is set up. It may well not be that simple, but give it a go and I hope it works!

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? If not, can you post the output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/` ?

Answer (score 0):

***Hi Run below command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change following parameter in grub file ->

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=native"
```

Save the file and run below commands:

```
sudo update-grub
```

reboot

Enjoy :)

---

Comment: I took your steps but unfortunately it didn't work. Do you know how it might have failed? Thank you

Comment: My comp is Lenovo and I use Ubuntu and the light button is not work. I try to do change the line as you is writing here but the button is not work.

Comment: Does not work with Ubuntu 22.04. The line referred to was:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=off"

I changed it as suggested here. No joy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to open new theme. May be smbd helps and save time.

**FIX brightness keys <kbd>F4</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> (instead of microphone key on brightness key) on HP Elitebook 840 G6.**

For Ubuntu 22.04 kernel 6.2.0.35

1. Turn off in UEFI `FN key automatically` disabled in `Settings`. It means that to change hotkeys you need push key <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>Hotkey</kbd>. Save changes.
2. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
   Comment line with `#` like in example an add `amdgpu.backlight=0`   (add all line)

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=amdgpu.backlight=0
```

3. `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

FIX for Ubuntu 22.04
After fixing from the previous message brightness regulation keys broke again. I found a method on the internet and want to share it with other people.

https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_1997208-1551050-16

> 1. Turn off the computer.
> 2. Disconnect the AC adapter.
> 3. Remove any discs from the disc drive.
> 4. Remove memory cards from the card reader slot.
> 5. Disconnect all nonessential peripheral devices, such as printers, scanners, external hard drives, and USB flash drives.
> 6. With the AC adapter unplugged, press and hold the power button for approximately 15 seconds.
> 7. Reconnect the AC adapter, and then turn on the computer.
>    Blockquote

It works for now!